# Propagator loop in Feynman diagram using tikz-feynman package

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

Consider the following code written using the `tikz-feynman` package:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
    \feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
        a -- b [dot] -- [out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=3cm] b -- c,
    };
\end{document}
```

This draws the following Feynman diagram:

[image]

I would like to make the line completely horizontal and turn the loop from an oval into a sphere?

How do you do this?

Comment: Hello, you should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to be able to help you

Comment: I can't reproduce your solution. With  testing`\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman} \begin{document} ` ...[your code here] `\end{document}`  -> the line will be horizontal. So you have to add a MWE.

Comment: Edited question to reflect your comment

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that the algorithm that [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) uses in order to place the vertices doesn't work well if it only has a straight line because the difference in the optimization between a mostly-straight and a fully-straight line are quite small.

This can be easily fixed by using an alternative layout algorithm, such as the layered layout in this case:

```
%% luatex85 is only necesary to fix a bug in standalone
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- b [dot] -- [out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=3cm] b -- c,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]