# Proper circle propagator loop using tikz-feynman package

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

Since I wasn't able to comment the answer to this question:

[Propagator loop in Feynman diagram using tikz-feynman package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/363803/propagator-loop-in-feynman-diagram-using-tikz-feynman-package)

I need to ask separately.
I was looking for the same thing except that I would like the propagator loop to be a proper circle. Does anybody know how this can be done?

```
%% luatex85 is only necesary to fix a bug in standalone
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- b [dot] -- [out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=3cm] b -- c,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the `{feynman}` environment within a `{tikzpicture}` which allows you to access all the commands from `TikZ`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\diagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
  a -- b [dot]--b--c
};
\path (b)--++(90:0.5) coordinate (A);
\draw (A) circle(0.5);
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That's quite nice! When using the feynman package this way, how can I manipulate the propagator circle characteristics, say I want it to be a [scalar]?

Comment: @uitty400, which circle characteristics, radius? If it is, add `\def\r{0.5}` and change the code with `\r`.

Comment: no, as I said I want the circle to represent a scalar particle, which is usually done by the `[scalar]` option, so that the circle shows as a dotted line.

Comment: @uitty400, `\draw [dotted] (A) circle(\r);`