# How to draw a colored Feynman diagram with tikz-feynman?

Tags: color, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to draw the diagram below on latex. I am not sure where to begin. I searched a lot but couldn't find any resolution. Here's what I faced:

It was easy to draw the line from left to right. But the rest had no slution. First I tried:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)] 
            \begin{feynman}
                \vertex (x);
                \vertex[right=5cm of x] (y);
                \vertex[right=2.5cm of x] (a);
                \diagram*{
                (x) --[fermion] (a),
                (a) --[fermion] (y),
                a --[fermion, out=135, in=45, loop, min distance=5 cm] a,
                };
            \end{feynman}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Feynman diagrams for two vertex $\phi^4$ interaction in real scalar field theory.} \label{fig:FD1}
    \end{figure}
```

But the result was not same. The loop is not elliptical as shown in the figure. It looked like the one in question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387810/proper-circle-propagator-loop-using-tikz-feynman-package).

The next problem was to put color inside the loop. I found some draw options. But then the colored region has circular/square/elliptic shapes, which do not coincide with the loop. I am at a complete loss. Is there any possible solution on this?

[image: FD]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The answer to the question that you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387823) is actually a pretty good starting point for how to draw the ellipse you want. I adapted my answer based on that answer, but I changed `circle` to ellipse and added a fill color of `ellipseFillColor`, and I set the text color to `backgroundTextColor` based on your screenshot. Furthermore, the `tikzfeynman/dot` at node `b` got covered by the fill of the ellipse, so I tacked on some Ti*k*Z code of my own at the end to ensure it was visible above the filled ellipse. This was my end result:

[image: A Feynman diagram with a fermion traveling to the right, then a loop, then continuing to the right]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{backgroundTextColor}{HTML}{8C6D0B}
\definecolor{ellipseFillColor}{HTML}{ADDCF0}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\color{backgroundTextColor}
\makeatletter
  \begin{feynman}
  \diagram [horizontal=a to b, layered layout] {
    a  [particle={$(p_n,\mathbf p)$}]
    -- [fermion]
    b  
    -- [fermion]
    c  [particle={$(p_n,\mathbf p)$}]
  };

  % Define a path to the center of the ellipse at point A1, and another point
  % to the top of the ellipse at point A2
  \path (b) --++ (90:0.6) coordinate (A1) --++ (0,0.65) coordinate (A2);
  
  % Next, draw the ellipse at point A, and color the inside
  \draw[
    fill = ellipseFillColor,
    decoration={
      markings,
      % This following part is borrowed from the tikzfeynman.keys.code.tex “with 
      % reversed arrow” style, but I changed the fill of the arrow to match the
      % fill color of the line. Otherwise, the arrow would have been blue like
      % the fill of the ellipse.
      mark=at position 0.25 with {\node[
        transform shape,
        xshift=0.5mm,
        rotate=180,
        fill=backgroundTextColor,
        inner sep=\tikzfeynman@arrow@size,
        draw=none,
        isosceles triangle
      ] {}; }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  ] (A1) ellipse (0.4 and 0.6);
  
  % Draw dot at node b
  \draw[fill = backgroundTextColor](b) circle (0.05) node[anchor=north] {$\lambda_1$};
  
  % Place text above ellipse
  \draw(A2) node[anchor=south] {$(r_n, \mathbf r)$};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This has solved almost all the issues. This was a very nice and complete answer. There are a couple of minor things I would like to ask as well. First of all, as in my original figure, you can see the vertices has names like (p_n,p). The comma is creating issues. Huge error appearing if I use the comma. The second issue is if I use PDFLatex, things get modified, the fefrmion lines get shortened. Do you think if I use vertices separately to define the a,b points, i can still use this in pdflatex? Lastly, now, if I am trying to write something else, the text has color.

Comment: @SamapanBhadury I'm happy this was useful! I've edited my answer to include the changes you want. To address your comment, (1) Ti*k*Z uses commas to see what keys are passed into a command, so it's mistaking your math for a new key. Surrounding the math with `{}` fixes this. (2) You can use pdflatex, but then it'll be up to you to manually make the diagram look pretty. The choice is yours. (3) `\color` changes the text color everywhere in its scope. Because I used `\color` within `document`, the color changed everywhere afterwards. Moving it inside `tikzpicture` fixes this.

Comment: Also, out of my own curiosity, what notation are you using? I'm especially interested in the squiggle beneath the letters p and r in your screenshot, and what they mean. I'm no particle physicist, but I'd love to learn more :)

Comment: Ah! it's simple 3-vector. I am not going to use it. Instead of arrow above, I wrote it as a squiggle below as a force of habit. Thanks again.